# Saving the image to gallery when I take the picture using the form from html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an HTML page that uploads the pictures to the desired location. But the problem is when i take the photo and upload it, it is not saved on the mobile device. I want to save the image as sometimes there are network issue and there is no internet connection for the file to upload. Below is the code i am using.

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image" id="image" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /><br/><br/>
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image1"  /><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you are uploading a photo from a mobile using HTML page and you want it to store in the SAME mobile device when there is no internet connection. Is this what you are asking ?

Comment: Yes.. Exactly the same.